# AWS Athena/CFT: Creating Athena workgroup 'Query result location' via CFT not working

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena

I have an AWS CloudFormation template in which I have the following Athena workgroup resource:

```
    "MyAthenaWorkgroup": {
      "Type": "AWS::Athena::WorkGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "Name": "athenaworkgroup",
        "Description": "Athena workgroup",
        "State": "ENABLED",
        "WorkGroupConfiguration": {
          "ResultConfiguration": {
            "OutputLocation": {
              "Fn::Sub": "s3://${InputS3BucketName}-parquet-output/query-results"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

My expected result after deployment is to see that the specified output location is used in the settings of the newly created Athena workgroup.

However, instead of this the behavior is that every time I select the workgroup in the AWS console Athena query editor, I get a popup as below:

[image]

Further, if I click acknowledge, the workgroup settings are not actually updated - and I still have to acknowledge explicitly this popup every time I switch back and forth between the workgroups.

Is there a way to modify my CFT resource to ensure the settings are updated, without explicitly requiring user confirmation (I need this to enable use of this from an external resource, Grafana).